# Ember Data belongsTo async relationship omitted from createRecord() save() serialization

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, rsvp-promise

Edit 11/16/14: Version Information

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.7.0 ember-1.7.0.js:14463
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.10+canary.30d6bf849b ember-1.7.0.js:14463
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2 ember-1.7.0.js:14463
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
```

---

I'm beating my head against a wall trying to do something that I think should be *fairly* straightforward with ember and ember-data, but I haven't had any luck so far.

Essentially, I want to use server data to populate a `<select>` dropdown menu.  When the form is submitted, a model should be created based on the data the user chooses to select.  The model is then saved with ember data and forwarded to the server with the following format:

```
{ 
    "File": { 
        "fileName":"the_name.txt",
        "filePath":"/the/path",
        "typeId": 13,
        "versionId": 2
    }
}
```

The problem is, the typeId and versionId are left out when the model relationship is defined as async like so:

```
App.File =  DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.belongsTo('type', {async: true}),
    version: DS.belongsTo('version', {async: true}),
    fileName: DS.attr('string'),
    filePath: DS.attr('string')
});
```

The part that is confusing me, and probably where my mistakes lie, is the controller:

```
App.FilesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['files'],
    uploadError: false,

    // These properties will be given by the binding in the view to the 
    //<select> inputs.  
    selectedType: null,
    selectedVersion: null,

    files: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.files'),

    actions: {
        createFile: function() {
            this.createFileHelper();
        }
    },

    createFileHelper: function() {
        var selectedType = this.get('selectedType');
        var selectedVersion = this.get('selectedVersion');

        var file = this.store.createRecord('file', {
                fileName: 'the_name.txt',
                filePath: '/the/path'
        });

        var gotDependencies = function(values) {

            //////////////////////////////////////
            // This only works when async: false
            file.set('type', values[0])
                .set('version', values[1]);
            //////////////////////////////////////

            var onSuccess = function() {
                this.transitionToRoute('files');
            }.bind(this);

            var onFail = function() {
                this.set('uploadError', true);
            }.bind(this);

            file.save().then(onSuccess, onFail);
        }.bind(this);

        Ember.RSVP.all([
            selectedType,
            selectedVersion
        ]).then(gotDependencies);
    }
});
```

When async is set to false, ember handles `createRecord().save()` POST requests correctly.

When async is true, ember handles GET requests perfectly with multiple requests, but does NOT add the belongsTo relationships to the file JSON during `createRecord().save()`.  Only the basic properties are serialized:

```
{"File":{"fileName":"the_name.txt","filePath":"/the/path"}}
```

**I realize this question has been asked before but I have not found a satisfactory answer thus far and I have not found anything that suits my needs.  So, how do I get the belongsTo relationship to serialize properly?**

Just to be sure that everything is here, I will add the custom serialization I have so far:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    serializeIntoHash: function(data, type, record, options) {
        var root = Ember.String.capitalize(type.typeKey);
        data[root] = this.serialize(record, options);
    },
    keyForRelationship: function(key, type){
        if (type === 'belongsTo') {
            key += "Id";
        }
        if (type === 'hasMany') {
            key += "Ids";
        }
        return key;
    }
});

App.FileSerializer = App.ApplicationSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        type: { serialize: 'id' },
        version: { serialize: 'id' }
    }
});
```

And a select:

```
{{ view Ember.Select
    contentBinding="controller.files.versions"
    optionValuePath="content"
    optionLabelPath="content.versionStr"
    valueBinding="controller.selectedVersion"
    id="selectVersion"
    classNames="form-control"
    prompt="-- Select Version --"}}
```

If necessary I will append the other routes and controllers (FilesRoute, FilesController, VersionsRoute, TypesRoute)

**EDIT** 11/16/14

I have a working solution (hack?) that I found based on information in two relevant threads:

1) [How should async belongsTo relationships be serialized?](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-should-async-belongsto-relationships-be-serialized/3858)

2) [Does async belongsTo support related model assignment?](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1542)

Essentially, all I had to do was move the `Ember.RSVP.all()` to after a `get()` on the properties:

```
createFileHelper: function() {
    var selectedType = this.get('selectedType');
    var selectedVersion = this.get('selectedVersion');

    var file = this.store.createRecord('file', {
            fileName: 'the_name.txt',
            filePath: '/the/path',
            type: null,
            version: null
    });


    file.set('type', values[0])
        .set('version', values[1]);

    Ember.RSVP.all([
        file.get('type'),
        file.get('version')
    ]).then(function(values) {

        var onSuccess = function() {
            this.transitionToRoute('files');
        }.bind(this);

        var onFail = function() {
            alert("failure");
            this.set('uploadError', true);
        }.bind(this);

        file.save().then(onSuccess, onFail);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

So I needed to `get()` the properties that were belongsTo relationships before I save the model.  I don't know is whether this is a bug or not.  Maybe someone with more knowledge about emberjs can help shed some light on that.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Any updates?

Comment: @torazaburo Are you `.get()`ing the properties before you're asking for the promise?  i.e. `set()` them and then use `.all()` or `.then()` on a `.get()`.  See my answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing `set` then `get(...).then(...)` and it's working but this seems to be seriously broken and I wondered if you can figured out something more "elegant", to the extent anything in Ember is ever elegant. Actually I'm not doing a separate `set` but rather passing the value in the hash to `createRecord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the question for more details, but the generic answer that I worked for me when saving a model with a belongsTo relationship (and you specifically need that relationship to be serialized) is to call `.get()` on the properties and then `save()` them in `then()`.

It boils down to this:

```
var file = this.store.createRecord('file', {
        fileName: 'the_name.txt',
        filePath: '/the/path',
        type: null,
        version: null
});

// belongsTo set() here
file.set('type', selectedType)
    .set('version', selectedVersion);

Ember.RSVP.all([
    file.get('type'),
    file.get('version')
]).then(function(values) {

    var onSuccess = function() {
        this.transitionToRoute('files');
    }.bind(this);

    var onFail = function() {
        alert("failure");
        this.set('uploadError', true);
    }.bind(this);

    // Save inside then() after I call get() on promises
    file.save().then(onSuccess, onFail);

}.bind(this));
```